# Algorithms To Generate Every Possible Combination of 7 Digit

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'm trying to find a algorithms to generate every possible combination of a 7 character string. The string must **ALWAYS** contain 3 numbers (0-9) and 4 letters (A-Z)

Example:
1GH2G2G, 
22JUYT1, 
HGTY222

But i need every possible combination of these. 
I'm using c++ but pseudo code is welcome.

**EDIT ( to clarify):** 
The question was to generate every possible combination of the following charset "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789" which is 7 characters long AND ALWAYS must contain 3 numbers (0-9) and 4 letters (A-Z). I have no base string to start with, the examples above was just to show what the output should be like.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: What have you tried, what didn't work? This sounds like it's not extremely difficult, please show us what you've attempted.

Comment: Seperately generate 3 numbers and 4 letters, put them into a string, and then shuffle.

Comment: Yes thats easy. The hard part is generating every single combination once.

Comment: @user3284667 Keyword:`lexical permutation`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this on for size. It's Pascal but you'll get the idea.

```
procedure GenerateCodes;
begin
  GenerateRest(7, 4, 3, '');
end;

procedure GenerateRest(
   CharsLeft, LettersLeft, DigitsLeft: Integer; 
   const Prefix: string);
var
  c: char;
begin
  if CharsLeft  = 0 then begin
    write(Prefix,' ');
    exit;
  end;

  if LettersLeft > 0 then
    for c := 'A' to 'Z' do
      GenerateRest(CharsLeft - 1, LettersLeft - 1, DigitsLeft, Prefix + c);

  if DigitsLeft > 0 then
    for c := '0' to '9' do
      GenerateRest(CharsLeft - 1, LettersLeft, DigitsLeft - 1, Prefix + c);
end;
```

Comment: You my friend are Awesomeness! Now to port to C++.